# Spaces in file path

Tags: c#, file, path, space

I'm creating a console application in C#, and I want to check if a specific file (`foo.exe`). But when the path contains spaces (`C:\A Folder With Spaces\`) it checks if `foo.exe` exists at this directory: `C:\A`.

Question: How can I check inside of a folder that contains spaces?

Comment: use the '@' sign for a string literal: @"C:\A Folder With Spaces\"

Comment: @ro-E Nope, that doesn't work

Comment: could you paste the actual code? @bramhaag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the name of the file as command-line parameter. In this case the split at the space is done by Windows `cmd` command processor when you pass `C:\A Folder With Spaces\` as parameter. To fix this, enclose the file name in doublequotes:

```
c:\test>myprog.exe "C:\A Folder With Spaces\foo.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If (File.Exists(@"C:\A Folder With Spaces\foo.exe")
{
    //the @ sign makes the spaces be taken literally.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're supplying the path as an argument to the console application? In which case enclose the path argument in quotes